# Create and return object from method

Tags: ruby

I'm just wondering if there is any more beautiful method to create object in the method and return it ?

Here is my code:

```
class Example
   def Example.load_from_file(filename)
     example = Example.new
     # some code
     example
   end
end
```

May be there is some Ruby idiom which allow me not to write `example` at the end of the method. Can you refactore this code or it is goog enough now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `example` that is mutable and you keep applying destructive methods to it within "some code":

```
class Example
  def Example.load_from_file(filename)
    Example.new.tap do |example|
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```